# can't upload "+" character to mysql with swift httppost body

Tags: mysql, swift, base64

[image]

I'm trying to upload decoded base64 string to server , but i can't send + chars , and the + symbols sent as empty space ,so i can't fetch the correct image
when in print in console everything is all right but in my db , the + chars replace with empty space
this is my code
thanks to help

enter code here

```
 let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        print("mine =" , image?.size.width)
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


           let mine = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!,0.5)

        let strBase64:String = "dfdfgdfg+dfgdfgbg"

       //print(strBase64)


        let myUrl = URL(string: "http://ahooradailymagazines.com/insert_user.php/");

        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

        let postString = "image=" + strBase64 + "&tinyImg=" + "mysty"

       request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            if error != nil
            {
                //print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

        }

        task.resume()
```

//this is the server code

```
[<?php
error_reporting ( 0 );
require_once 'include.php';

$connect = @mysqli_connect ( $hostname, $username, $password, $database );
if ($connect) {
    @mysqli_query ( $connect, "SET CHARACTER SET utf8;" );
} 

else {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno () . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error () . PHP_EOL;
    exit ();
}

// array for JSON response
$response = array ();
$image = $_POST \['image'\];
$tiny_img = $_POST\['tinyImg'\];



$insertquery = "insert into users(image,tiny_image) values ('$image','$tiny_img')";
$getIdQuery = "select user_id ,image from users where image='$image'";
@mysqli_query ( $connect, $insertquery );

 $result_giq = mysqli_query($connect, $getIdQuery);

$row = @mysqli_fetch_row ( $result_giq);
$response \['ads'\] = array ();
$ads = array ();
$ads \['id'\] = $row \[0\];
$ads \['image'\] = $row \[1\];
array_push ( $response \['ads'\], $ads );
echo json_encode ( $response ); 

// echoing JSON response
// echo json_encode ( $response );

?>][1]
```

Comment: show server code that is not getting your string correctly, you said that you have a problem there

Comment: added a picture and the server code , its the pic linkhttps://i.stack.imgur.com/u7NKZ.png

Comment: Assuming actual code is not full of random backslashes, you are using mysqli incorrectly. Please check the documentation on how to configure it to throw exceptions on error and  how to inject user input into queries.

Comment: but i think this line deletes the +                                                request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift post request encoding plus sign become white space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36854981/swift-post-request-encoding-plus-sign-become-white-space)